# Paypal ExpressCheckout LANDINGPAGE not working anymore?

Tags: paypal

I have been using LANDINGPAGE='Billing' to get customers directly to Credit card payment page instead of  Paypal account login page.
But for some reason it doesn't work anymore. I suspect this is since the new paypal design update.
Has anyone encountered the same problem ?
Is this a known bug ? 
Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a new parameter you need to include in order for the new landing pages to function like you're wanting.  Leave LANDINGPAGE=Billing&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole like you must be doing already, but then also include USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard.  That should give you what you're after on the new pages (although it's still not quite as prominent as it is on the old pages.)

You also need to make sure you're using at least VERSION=109.0, which is [when this was introduced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/merchant/PayPal_Merchant_API_Release_Notes_109/).

Here's a sample of a request I just did and a screenshot of the PayPal screen based on this request.

```
11-26-2014 @ 03:50:52 - Request: Array
(
    [USER] => *****
    [PWD] => *****
    [VERSION] => 112.0
    [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_SP_WooCommerce
    [SIGNATURE] => *****
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [MAXAMT] => 150.00
    [RETURNURL] => http://www.angelleye.com/checkout/review-order/?pp_action=revieworder
    [CANCELURL] => http://www.angelleye.com/cart/
    [BRANDNAME] => Angell EYE
    [CUSTOMERSERVICENUMBER] => 555-555-5555
    [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
    [LANDINGPAGE] => Billing
    [USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE] => CreditCard
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 75.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Premium Support
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 75.00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 75
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrew. I already found out about USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard and I tried using latest version 119, and now also 116, but it doesn't solve anything. Still the same page proposing to log in to your paypal account and a grey button below to pay without an account.

Comment: I've added more detail to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I get the same landing page. But I'd like the landing page to be the page you get when you click on "Pay with debit or credit card" button. I suppose it is not possible then ?

Comment: Nope, that's as good as the new landing pages get for guest checkout at this point.

Comment: Ok that's bad news for me. Hope they will improve this. And there is no way to get the old version of the checkout page ? I noticed the old version appears sometimes when you cancel and go back to the shop and then try again.

Comment: What they're doing is split testing the two, so sometimes you'll see the old one and sometimes you'll see the new one.  They're doing that to compare conversion rates and fine-tune the pages as much as they can to benefit us all.  So no, you can't control it more than what you've done, but they're working to make it the best possible way based on stats over time.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Do you happen to have an update on what happened with this? Is the page like you posted in the screenshot now the only version? I've wasted a lot of time trying to figure out how to send users directly to the credit card form, but now as far as I can tell PayPal has made that impossible.

Comment: Still works fine for me.  What screen are you getting?

Comment: I meant that you still can't send users directly to the credit card payment form. The only page I'm seeing now is the one you posted in your screenshot where it displays a "Pay with Debit or Credit Card" button.

Comment: Ah, well yeah, that is out of our control unfortunately, but you can use Payments Pro to process cards directly on your site.